# Can I override a C++ virtual function within Python with Cython?

Tags: c++, python, cython

I have a C++ class with a virtual method:

```
//C++
class A
{

    public:
        A() {};
        virtual int override_me(int a) {return 2*a;};
        int calculate(int a) { return this->override_me(a) ;}

};
```

What I would like to do is to expose this class to Python with Cython, inherit from this class in Python and have the correct overridden called:

```
#python:
class B(PyA):
   def override_me(self, a):
       return 5*a
b = B()
b.calculate(1)  # should return 5 instead of 2
```

Is there a way to do this ? 
Now I'm thinking, it could also be great if we could override the virtual method in Cython as well (in a pyx file), but allowing users to do this in pure python is more important.

**Edit**: If this helps, a solution could be to use the pseudocode given here: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/pyrex_differences.html#cpdef-functions

But there are two problems then :

- I don't know how to write this pseudocode in Cython
- maybe there is a better approach

Comment: yes of course. It returns 2. Do you need the pyx source as well (which  is plain wrong but I could not find a fix for it yet)?

Comment: No, I don't think I can help.  I think boost.python supports this.

Comment: Indeed, I did it with boost.python years ago. Now I would like to try alternatives to boost.python (too long to compile, resulting module too big, ...). If Cython can handle this I think that the rest will go smoothly.

Comment: I don't think this is supported directly, but a workaround has been [mentioned on the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/cython-users/browse_thread/thread/bc007d85b2ccc518/de3c1cf9acf7b111).

Comment: Another workaround would be using a strategy pattern or something similar instead of method overloading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Excellent !

Not complete but sufficient.
I've been able to do the trick for my own purpose. Combining this post with the sources linked above.
It's not been easy, since I'm a beginner at Cython, but I confirm that it is the only way I could find over the www.

Thanks a lot to you guys.

I am sorry that I don't have so much time go into textual details, but here are my files (might help to get an additional point of view on how to put all of this together)

setup.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [
    Extension("elps", 
              sources=["elps.pyx", "src/ITestClass.cpp"],
              libraries=["elp"],
              language="c++",
              )
    ]
)
```

TestClass :

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H_
#define TESTCLASS_H_


namespace elps {

class TestClass {

public:
    TestClass(){};
    virtual ~TestClass(){};

    int getA() { return this->a; };
    virtual int override_me() { return 2; };
    int calculate(int a) { return a * this->override_me(); }

private:
    int a;

};

} /* namespace elps */
#endif /* TESTCLASS_H_ */
```

ITestClass.h :

```
#ifndef ITESTCLASS_H_
#define ITESTCLASS_H_

// Created by Cython when providing 'public api' keywords
#include "../elps_api.h"

#include "../../inc/TestClass.h"

namespace elps {

class ITestClass : public TestClass {
public:
    PyObject *m_obj;

    ITestClass(PyObject *obj);
    virtual ~ITestClass();
    virtual int override_me();
};

} /* namespace elps */
#endif /* ITESTCLASS_H_ */
```

ITestClass.cpp :

```
#include "ITestClass.h"

namespace elps {

ITestClass::ITestClass(PyObject *obj): m_obj(obj) {
    // Provided by "elps_api.h"
    if (import_elps()) {
    } else {
        Py_XINCREF(this->m_obj);
    }
}

ITestClass::~ITestClass() {
    Py_XDECREF(this->m_obj);
}

int ITestClass::override_me()
{
    if (this->m_obj) {
        int error;
        // Call a virtual overload, if it exists
        int result = cy_call_func(this->m_obj, (char*)"override_me", &error);
        if (error)
            // Call parent method
            result = TestClass::override_me();
        return result;
    }
    // Throw error ?
    return 0;
}

} /* namespace elps */
```

EDIT2 : A note about PURE virtual methods (it appears to be a quite recurrent concern). As shown in the above code, in that particular fashion, "TestClass::override_me()" CANNOT be pure since it has to be callable in case the method is not overridden in the Python's extended class (aka : one doesn't fall in the "error"/"override not found" part of the "ITestClass::override_me()" body).

Extension : elps.pyx :

```
cimport cpython.ref as cpy_ref

cdef extern from "src/ITestClass.h" namespace "elps" :
    cdef cppclass ITestClass:
        ITestClass(cpy_ref.PyObject *obj)
        int getA()
        int override_me()
        int calculate(int a)

cdef class PyTestClass:
    cdef ITestClass* thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
       ##print "in TestClass: allocating thisptr"
       self.thisptr = new ITestClass(<cpy_ref.PyObject*>self)
    def __dealloc__(self):
       if self.thisptr:
           ##print "in TestClass: deallocating thisptr"
           del self.thisptr

    def getA(self):
       return self.thisptr.getA()

#    def override_me(self):
#        return self.thisptr.override_me()

    cpdef int calculate(self, int a):
        return self.thisptr.calculate(a) ;


cdef public api int cy_call_func(object self, char* method, int *error):
    try:
        func = getattr(self, method);
    except AttributeError:
        error[0] = 1
    else:
        error[0] = 0
        return func()
```

Finally, the python calls :

```
from elps import PyTestClass as TC;

a = TC(); 
print a.calculate(1);

class B(TC):
#   pass
    def override_me(self):
        return 5

b = B()
print b.calculate(1)
```

This should make the previous linked work hopefully more straight to the point we're discussing here...

EDIT : On the other hand the above code could be optimized by using 'hasattr' instead of try/catch  block :

```
cdef public api int cy_call_func_int_fast(object self, char* method, bint *error):
    if (hasattr(self, method)):
        error[0] = 0
        return getattr(self, method)();
    else:
        error[0] = 1
```

The above code, of course, makes a difference only in the case where we don't override the 'override_me' method.

Comment: Just a note for those who want to try this example: the implementation of TestClass() and ~TestClass() is missing. This will cause an error like "ImportError: ./elps.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN4elps9TestClassE
". Just add an empty inline implementation

Comment: Is there, with your solution, a way to expose virtual methods (ie override_me() ) to the Python side?

Comment: As long as you change the name, you should be able to: `def call_override_me(self):     return self.thisptr.override_me()`??

Comment: I would prefer to keep the same name. But I now have an idea: cy_call_func_int_fast could check if override_me has been overridden. It would need to compare the method override_me from the class and from the instanciated object like `if PyTestClass.override_me != self.__class__.override_me`. Maybe it could work...

Comment: Ok, please keep us posted about that. And thanks for the edit (inline constr/destr) ;)

Comment: From my tests it seems to work. In cy_call_func instead of looking for attribute "override_me", perform the check `if self.__class__.override_me == PyA.override_me`. If true then set the error to 1 (we must use the C++ version). If false then use the Python version since it has been overloaded. This way you can uncomment the `def override_me(self)` in your pyx file.

Comment: I have an implementation [here](https://github.com/dashesy/pyavfcam/blob/master/src/avf.pyx#L27) that I pass `args` and `kwargs` to be more generic function. To actually create `args` and `kwargs` one can use `Py_BuildValue` for simple constructs or resort to another [public api](https://github.com/dashesy/pyavfcam/blob/master/src/avf.pyx#L19) to have Cython do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 11):

The solution is somewhat complicated, but it is possible.  There is a fully working example here: https://bitbucket.org/chadrik/cy-cxxfwk/overview

Here is an overview of the technique:

Create a specialized subclass of `class A` whose purpose will be to interact with a cython extension:

```
// created by cython when providing 'public api' keywords:
#include "mycymodule_api.h"

class CyABase : public A
{
public:
  PyObject *m_obj;

  CyABase(PyObject *obj);
  virtual ~CyABase();
  virtual int override_me(int a);
};
```

The constructor takes a python object, which is the instance of our cython extension:

```
CyABase::CyABase(PyObject *obj) :
  m_obj(obj)
{
  // provided by "mycymodule_api.h"
  if (import_mycymodule()) {
  } else {
    Py_XINCREF(this->m_obj);
  }
}

CyABase::~CyABase()
{
  Py_XDECREF(this->m_obj);
}
```

Create an extension of this subclass in cython, implementing all non-virtual methods in the standard fashion

```
cdef class A:
    cdef CyABase* thisptr
    def __init__(self):
        self.thisptr = new CyABase(
            <cpy_ref.PyObject*>self)

    #------- non-virutal methods --------
    def calculate(self):
        return self.thisptr.calculate()
```

Create virtual and pure virtual methods as `public api` functions, that take as arguments the extension instance, the method arguments, and an error pointer:

```
cdef public api int cy_call_override_me(object self, int a, int *error):
    try:
        func = self.override_me
    except AttributeError:
        error[0] = 1
        # not sure what to do about return value here...
    else:
        error[0] = 0
        return func(a)
```

Utilize these function in your c++ intermediate like this:

```
int
CyABase::override_me(int a)
{
  if (this->m_obj) {
    int error;
    // call a virtual overload, if it exists
    int result = cy_call_override_me(this->m_obj, a, &error);
    if (error)
      // call parent method
      result = A::override_me(i);
    return result;
  }
  // throw error?
  return 0;
}
```

I quickly adapted my code to your example, so there could be mistakes.  Take a look at the full example in the repository and it should answer most of your questions.  Feel free to fork it and add your own experiments, it's far from complete!

Comment: This is a great start, thanks a lot. But can the override_me() method be called by a Python script? If this method is not pure virtual in C++ then one should be able to call it from the Python part

Comment: I've put together a guide https://monadical.com/posts/virtual-classes-in-cython.html